# Problem connection deep web site .onion white page with links

Tags: onion-services, connection

I have looked for my answer but I can not find and come to you...
It is impossible for me to access deep web sites, I know the problem does not come from these sites.
Here is what happens: when i try to go on the "french hidden wiki" https://frwikisfa6myvgyx.onion.cab/ I just have a wholly blank page that appears with only this link https: // Frwikisfa6myvgyx.onion.cab/20.08.2017, and when I click on it does not happen anything ...
The security level is high, noscript enabled, I tried with and without bridge, I have downloaded and removed several times Tor, the problem still persists ...
I use xubuntu, windows 7, tails, the problem and the same for all ...
Last year I often come on the deepweb .onion with a computer equipped with windows 8 then 10 and I have never had this kind of problem ...
I attach a picture of the problem.
Please help me I find the solution nowhere ...
Sorry for my English I use google translate ...
thank you very much.[image]

Comment: So why are .cab sites no longer accessible when it would work very well before?

Comment: Some tor2web instaces cache content, so the onion service can be down but it still appears on the tor2web because it's in their cache.

Comment: onion.cab is/was a clearnet website running a [tor2web](https://tor2web.org/) proxy - allowing 'normal' (clearnet) web-browsers to see the 'darknet' content. since you have tor-browser you can view this content directly, like so (without the .cab): http://frwikisfa6myvgyx.onion